# Convert Output Seconds to Time Format c# console

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

How to convert seconds output to Minutes: Seconds Format?

I want to do this using this code.

I can see only seconds.

Just want to display Min:Sec type (No Hours)
im using .net 2.0

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using threadTimer = System.Threading;

namespace TimerExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        static int i = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {     
        
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n 1st");
            timer.Elapsed+=timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start(); 
            threadTimer.Thread.Sleep (3000);  
            Console.Clear ();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n 2nd");
            threadTimer.Thread.Sleep (3000);  
        }

        private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            Console.Write("\r  Time Passed:  " + i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using .net 2.0? In .NET > 4.0 you can convert seconds to TimeSpan and convert back to a string in the format you need.

Comment: Use a `TimeSpan` instead of an integer and convert *that* to a string. No modern OS uses `\r` and a newline either. Use `Console.WriteLine("    Time Passed:    {0}",thatTime);` instead, or even `Console.WriteLine($"    Time Passed:    {thatTime}");`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: can u please help he with code? many thanks bro. :) . Then i will marked it as answer. :)

Comment: @Norbert Forgacs : Yes, i want to make an program that can run on older windows 7 sp0

Answer (score 0):

i found working answer.
This works as expected.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using threadTimer = System.Threading;

namespace TimerExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        static int i = 0;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {     
            
  
timer.Elapsed+=timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start(); 
       Console.WriteLine("1st");
            
            
             threadTimer.Thread.Sleep (3000);  
             Console.Clear ();
             Console.Clear ();
           Console.WriteLine("2nd");
           threadTimer.Thread.Sleep (3000);  
            
        }

        private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            float TimeToMissionsReady =  i++;
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeToMissionsReady);
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00 Minutes} and {1:00 Seconds}",
            ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
            Console.Write("\r   Time Passed:  " + elapsedTime);
        }
        
        

        
        
    }
}
```